# Probability junk email

Tags: probability

How would you solve this problem?

> You have just installed a system to detect junk email. The system can identify junk messages in 99% of cases. Nevertheless, the system says that a message is junk when it isn’t in 2% of
>   cases. Given that 10% of received emails are junk, what is the probability that a message truly is junk
>   when the system says it is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: Write down the conditional probabilities.

Comment: Just work through what happens to 1000 random messages: how many are junk?  How many are not?  How many are falsely classified as non-junk, etc.?  Finally, how many of the messages that got classified as junk actually are junk?  This is exactly the same calculation Bayes's theorem gives you, but it shows that the logic is really just "applied common sense" and actually reading the question.